# Stretch image on top of a button in order to push view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

I have this image which is UIButton:

[image: before]

I want to add some kind of gesture (pan gesture) to slide it to the right and I want the image to stretch to the right also like this:

[image: after]

It's very similar to the iPhone's "Slide to unlock" methods but without the same image that moves around from left to right.

Is it possible to do that?

EDIT:

I've added a UIPanGestureRecognizer to my button like this:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonDidDragged:)];
[self.buttonAbout addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

self.buttonFrame = self.buttonAbout.frame;
```

Also I saved the button frame into a CGRect.

Now this is the 'buttonDidDragged' methods, but I also have a problem, the button seems to go to the right but the image remains the same image. it will not stretch.

```
- (IBAction)buttonDidDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.view];

//    gesture.view.center = CGPointMake(gesture.view.center.x + translation.x, gesture.view.center.y);

    NSLog(@"%f",gesture.view.frame.origin.x + gesture.view.frame.size.width);
    gesture.view.frame = CGRectMake(gesture.view.frame.origin.x,
                                    gesture.view.frame.origin.y,
                                    gesture.view.frame.size.width + translation.x,
                                    gesture.view.frame.size.height);

    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)gesture.view;
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"about_us_button.png"];
    buttonImage = [buttonImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 80, 0, 0)];
    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             CGPoint finalPoint = CGPointMake(self.buttonFrame.origin.x + (self.buttonFrame.size.width / 2),
                                                              self.buttonFrame.origin.y + (self.buttonFrame.size.height / 2));
//                             gesture.view.center = finalPoint;
                             button.frame = newFrame; // This is where you change the frame of the button to make it stretch.
                         } completion:nil];
    }


    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: guys I'm off work, but first thing on sunday I'll check the answers. Thanks alot to all of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this,
In `.h`

```
CGSize dragViewSize;
```

then,

```
-(IBAction)buttonDidDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.view];

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        dragViewSize = gesture.view.frame.size;

    } else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGRect _rect = gesture.view.frame;
        _rect.size.width=dragViewSize.width+translation.x;
        gesture.view.frame = _rect;

    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    }
}
```

Its working fine... hope it will helps you...

Answer (score 1):

Nice idea! Yes, this is possible. You can have three images, left, right and center, the center one being just one pixel wide.

You can adjust the image in `touchesMoved`. There you can calculate the necessary stretch width based on the location of the touch.

The stretching is pretty easy with methods like

<strike>[UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight]</strike>

```
(UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets 
                          resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode
```

Comment: As an aside, using the method `[[UIImage imageNamed:@""] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topEdge, leftEdge, bottomEdge, rightEdge)];` gives even more control on how you can stretch the image.

Comment: @YossiTsafar: `- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight` is deprecated. So it is not wise to use this. Do as @msgambel suggests if you need iOS 5 support or use  `- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode` for iOS 6+

Comment: @msgambel still can't figure out how to do that. It won't work. the button slides to the right, but the image remins the same. Can you tell me why is that?

Comment: @YossiTsafar, it looks like you are animating the centre point, but not the frame itself. If you increase the width of the button image in the animation block, that should allow the image to stretch.

Comment: changed it back again, but nothing. I edited my code check it please. I dont know why the image is not stretching.

Comment: @YossiTsafar, I edited your code. The `frame` property is what you have to change in order to stretch the button. Hope That Helps!

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment to Mundi the method `- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight` is deprecated and it is therefore not wise to use it in any new development.

You should therefore as per @msgambel suggestion move on to `- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets` for iOS 5+ compatibility or even better `- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode` for iOS 6+ compatibility.

Never use a deprecated method :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this is what I did and it worked just great. Thank you very much everyone!

```
CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.view];
UIButton *button = (UIButton*)gesture.view;

if (translation.x < kTranslationMaximum && translation.x > kTranslationMinimum)
{
    self.aboutCenterImage.frame = CGRectMake(self.aboutCenterImage.frame.origin.x,
    self.aboutCenterImage.frame.origin.y,
    translation.x,
    self.aboutCenterImage.frame.size.height);

    gesture.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.aboutCenterImage.frame.origin.x + self.aboutCenterImage.frame.size.width,
    self.aboutCenterImage.frame.origin.y,
    self.buttonAbout.frame.size.width,
    self.aboutCenterImage.frame.size.height);
}
else if (translation.x > kTranslationMaximum)
{
    // Push ViewController or do whatever you like to do :)
}
```